# Geometric Matrix Multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I'm working on a project building a geometric (as opposed to arithmetic) neural net. To construct the transfer function, I would like to use geometric summation instead of arithmetic summation.

To make things clearer, I'm just going to describe in code:

```
def arithmetic_matrix_multiplication(matrix1, matrix2):
    new_matrix = np.zeros(len(matrix1),len(matrix2[0]))
    for i in range(len(matrix1)):
        for j in range(len(matrix2[0])):
            for k in range(len(matrix2)):
                new_matrix[i][j] += matrix1[i][k]*matrix2[k][j]
    return new_matrix

def geometric_matrix_multiplication(matrix1, matrix2):
    new_matrix = np.ones(len(matrix1),len(matrix2[0]))
    for i in range(len(matrix1)):
        for j in range(len(matrix2[0])):
            for k in range(len(matrix2)):
                new_matrix[i][j] *= matrix1[i][k]*matrix2[k][j]
    return new_matrix
```

As you can see, it's a pretty minimal change. The only problem is that, in the same way I would never actually write and use the above arithmetic code (I would use `numpy.dot`), I would really not like to actually use the geometric code above. Is there any way to leverage numpy's matrix multiplication to achieve the geometric result? I haven't been able to think of one, and I haven't found anything obvious past the solution above, which is far from optimal.

Comment: As written, won't your geometric result (assuming `zero` behaves vaguely like `np.zeros`) always be the zero matrix?  Should you start from the ones matrix instead?

Comment: @DSM Ah, whoops. You're totally right.

Comment: Are we lucky enough that all the elements are > 0?

Comment: @DSM Lol, of course. All < 1 too if that helps.

Comment: It isn't hard to write this in as a C extention if you learn the new NpyIter.

Comment: @seberg Do you have a doc/example link?

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.iterator.html#NpyIter_AdvancedNew and `np.nditer`. If you pass the right stuff into that, the loop itself is trivial. I would suggest to first program it with `np.nditer` and then translate it into C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are all complicating things unnecessarily... Since you have a single operation, multiplication, which is commutative, you can swap the order in which you perform them at will, i.e. you don't need to multiply items of `matrix1` with items of `matrix2`, and once you have computed all of them, multiply them together. Instead, you can first multiply all the relevant items of `matrix1` together, then all the relevant items of `matrix2` together, and then multiply the two resulting values. So you can write your function as the very simple:

```
def fast_geometric_matrix_multiplication(matrix1, matrix2):
    return np.prod(matrix1, axis=1)[:, None] * np.prod(matrix2, axis=0)
```

It has the additional advantage that, if you are multiplying matrices of shapes `(m, k)` and `(k, n)`, you would expect to be having to do `m*n*2*k` multiplications, while this method only requires `m*k + n*k + m*n`, which is bound to be much smaller than what you presently are doing for almost any array shapes.

And of course:

```
In [24]: a = np.random.rand(100, 200)
    ...: b = np.random.rand(200, 50)
    ...: 

In [25]: np.allclose(geometric_matrix_multiplication(a, b),
    ...:             fast_geometric_matrix_multiplication(a, b))
Out[25]: True

In [26]: %timeit geometric_matrix_multiplication(a, b)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.39 s per loop

In [27]: %timeit fast_geometric_matrix_multiplication(a, b)
10000 loops, best of 3: 74.2 us per loop

In [28]: %timeit np.prod(a[:, None, :]*b[..., None].T, axis=2)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.97 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

```
In [373]: %paste
x = np.arange(5*5, dtype=np.long).reshape(5,5)
y = np.arange(5*5, 5*5*2, dtype=np.long).reshape(5,5)
xy = geometric_matrix_multiplication(x,y)
xy2 = np.prod(x[:, None, :]*y.T[..., None], axis=2)
np.allclose(xy, xy2)

## -- End pasted text --
Out[373]: True
```

This solution is not very stable with regards of what shapes it can handle. So great if it works, but not something you should use for anything long term, if your data size is variable.

Comment: Nice.  This is much better than my answer because it doesn't restrict the values in the matrices.

Comment: beat me to it. the only trouble with this approach is that we need to form the full ixjxk matrix, whereas the operation in log space could (although currently does not use) a directly contracting operation. if your matrices get big, this could become a correspondingly big deal.

Comment: note that we don't 'need' to do any such thing fundamentally; but unless im missing some clever trick, the numpy api does not provide any optimized operations for multiplying-contractions. Id resort to numba if this were to be an issue.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn: I'm not aware of any either.  Pre-numba I wound up writing cython when I needed a more generic "einop" than einsum provided.

Comment: @DSM you should undelete your solution, this solution isn't very stable in regards of what shapes it can handle. The broadcasting fails  for some shapes.

Comment: After further investigation. This method combined with numba's autojit  provided the best results by far.

Comment: If you reverse the order of your operations, i.e. first do the reduction with `np.prod`, then do the multiplication, you avoid the huge intermediate array, and get an algorithmic advantage, from O(n^3) to O(n^2), see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a quite perfect candidate for [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/). The only thing you should have to add is `@autojit`. Of course you would also optimize the nested calls for the iteration length. `range` and `xrange` are treated both as simple for-loops by numba (without the overhead to create large arrays). In the end it could look like this:

```
from numba import autojit

@autojit
def geometric_matrix_multiplication(matrix1, matrix2):
    new_matrix = np.ones((len(matrix1),len(matrix2[0])))
    jlen = len(matrix2[0])
    klen = len(matrix2)
    for i in range(len(matrix1)):
        for j in range(jlen):
            for k in range(klen):
                new_matrix[i,j] *= matrix1[i,k]*matrix2[k,j]
    return new_matrix
```

By making use of jit compiling for this function, you should get C-like speed afterwards. To give some idea of the speed gain:

```
a = np.random.rand(100*100).reshape((100,100))
b = np.random.rand(100*100).reshape((100,100))

%timeit geometric_matrix_multiplication_org(a,b)
1 loops, best of 3: 4.1 s per loop

%timeit geometric_matrix_multiplication(a,b)
100 loops, best of 3: 5 ms per loop
```

Comment: Looks like a really cool library, but the optimization for matrix multiplication actually extends into the complexity of the operation, so there are deeper problems than just optimizing the for loops.

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow. You said, that you would never write code like your example in Python. I would agree, as the function would run quite slow in pure Python. But with jit compilation, this style of writing code is exactly the way to go, as for-loops suddenly get blazingly fast.

Comment: Heh, you could hope for memory access optimization, but doing that all the way gets you into a different level of complexity.

Comment: This method has a pretty big overhead, but actually has a lower complexity than the other two methods. The breakeven point was at around n=100000. After that the numba method is the clear victor. Before that though @M4rtini's method is considerably faster.

Comment: Looked back at this, and looks like adding `numba`'s `autojit` to M4rtini's method gave it the same reduced complexity.